# Backbone bind model attribute to input

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In Backbone is there a bind a model attribute to an input field so that when the input value changes the model attribute will be automatically set to the current value?

At the moment I have the following in my view

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-input" value="<%- model.firstname %>" />
```

Then in the view I listen to the following event and set the model attribute accordingly

```
events: {
    "keydown .form-input": "setAttribute"
},

setAttribute: function() {
    //Use model.set on the attribute that was changed
}
```

To me this seems like a bad way of doing it.  Am I missing an easier way of doing it?

Comment: joews is correct; your code is perfectly fine for Backbone. Why does it seem bad to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the right way to do it with vanilla Backbone. If you would like to set up automated data binding you'll need a plugin like [Epoxy](http://epoxyjs.org/).

Using Epoxy, your example would look something like:

```
var BindingView = Backbone.Epoxy.View.extend({
  bindings: {
    "[name=firstname]": "value:firstName",
  }
});
```

This binds the model's `firstName` attribute to the input with `name="firstname"`.